# Why checking undefined type instead of just value?

Tags: javascript

I got recently such legacy code:

```
if (typeof value != "undefined" && value.someOperation()) { }
```

I understand that its preventing undefined object issue, however isn't simple to do such thing:

```
if (value && value.someOperation()) { }
```

Is somewhere in deep javascript a hack or some situation that it would not work at all? There is no possible to get `0` or `false` instead of that object here. I wonder if I can change the first expression to the second one and I wouldn't break anything.

Comment: If you're sure that `value` is always going to be an Object, you can use the second code.

Comment: if you absolutely _know_ that `value` is either `undefined`, or is an object with that method as a property, then the latter is fine.

Comment: @GolezTrol it's stricter, but unnecessarily so - if `value` was `0`, for example, the code would still fail because the `.someOperation` method doesn't exist.

Comment: p.s. I've voted to close this because it's "primarily opinion based".  FWIW, I'd normally use the latter.

Comment: It is not opinion based, because I am asking whether changing the first one to the second one might broke anything.

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
if (typeof value != "undefined" && value.someOperation()) { }
```

`typeof value != "undefined"` is evaluated to false if and only if `value` is either `null` or `undefined`. However, if the value is either `0` or `false` then it will evaluate to true, and hence move on to second condition `value.someOperation()`.

> There is no possible to get 0 or false instead of that object here.

If the value of `value` cannot be `0` or `false`, even then you might want to check `value.someOperation` before checking `value.someOperation()` since `value.someOperation()` it may give following error

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

In fact, in both cases you might want to check if `value.someOperation` first before `value.someOperation()` i.e.

```
if (value && value.someOperation && value.someOperation()) { }
```

or

```
if (typeof value != "undefined" && value.someOperation && value.someOperation()) { }
```